# javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a way to get one object property from the value of another property

for example (in SQL) Get *id* from *object* where *object.name*="somename" ?

I need to get the id of that object, but I only know the name.

Comment: At first I thought I had commented twice... too similar nicknames, too similar questions xD

Comment: Yes, it's in an array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are trying to do this with an array of objects, because it doesn't make sense otherwise.

Depending on your desired browser support there is a method called `filter` on `Array.prototype`. If needed you can shim it too.

The code would end up looking something like this:

```
var list = ​[
    {id:1, name:'bob'},
    {id:2, name:'jim'},
    {id:3, name:'sam'},
    {id:4, name:'tim'}
];

var sams = list.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.name == 'sam';
});

console.log(sams[0].id);
```

Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/g8rTA/

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear that I was trying to filter through an array. Thanks for the help

Comment: +1 for `filter` approach and mentioning its not supported everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to get it:

```
function getObjectByAttribute(list, attr, val){
    var result = null;
    $.each(list, function(index, item){
        if(item[attr].toString() == val.toString()){
           result = item;
           return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var obj = getObjectByAttribute(yourList, 'name', 'somename');
if(obj) console.log(obj.id);
```

EDIT:

As @nnnnnn suggested, the non-jQuery alternative:

```
function getObjectByAttribut(list, attr, val){
    var result = null;
    for(var ind in list){
        if(list[ind][attr] == val) return list[ind];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Or, without jQuery, just use a plain `for` loop instead of `$.each()`. Can I suggest that you don't need the `result` variable? Just return `item` directly if found, and return `null` directly if not found (or even use `undefined` as the not-found value and then you don't even need the final `return` statement).

Comment: Yep, you are right, I should have taken that in account. Regarding the return false thing, you returning a non-false from a jQuery .each loop works like a continue statement in a foor loop, while returning false the loop is broken.

Comment: My apologies. In my mind I'd already jumped ahead to the non-jQuery version but of course with `$.each()` you do need `result` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, but I am answering this line.

*Is there a way to get one object property from the value of another property.*

```
var obj = {
   'name' : 'ramesh',
   'surname' : 'suresh'
}

var obj2 = {
   'props' : 'name',
   'method' : 'blah'
}


for(var i in obj){
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      if(i === obj2['props']){
         console.log('Found ' + i);    // This will find 'name'
         break; 
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: One more -1 in SO without comment :)

Comment: It was me, here's your comment: You're crazy.

Comment: ;) ha ha. I liked ur comment. But seriously, I was hoping for a better comment. This is not a place to laugh at somebody. Point out the mistake , so I can learn .

Comment: You haven't done anything 'wrong' exactly... (You fixed the `hasOwnProperty` call.) You just chose a very weird way to interpret his question.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` was a typo. I interpreted the line, I mentioned. Anyways, you just chose a very weird way to mark my weird interpretation.

Comment: There's nothing 'weird' about downvotes, it's the way the site works.

Comment: @JamesPoulson, Yes thats the reason , I upvoted his answer :)